# Can't render autoform template

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have a schema with collection:

```
export const Cources = new Meteor.Collection('Cources');

Cources.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  courcePath: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Cource path'
  },
  courceTitle: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Cource title',
    max: 200
  },
  courceDescription: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Cource description'
  },
  lessonsNumber: {
    type: Number,
    label: 'Lessons number',
    min: 1
  },
  courceDuration: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Cource duration'
  }
});

Cources.attachSchema(Cources.schema);
```

And template:

```
<template name="AddCource_page">
  <div class="container">
    {{> quickForm collection="Cources" id="insertCourceForm" type="insert"}}
  </div>
</template>
```

But, form is not rendering and there is error in console: `Error: Cources is not in the window scope`. And the same problems, when I add helpers. How do I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: You probably mean `Course` not `Cource`. Anyway, does it work if you remove `export const`?

Comment: try removing  `Course.schema` and instead use `coursesSchema`

Answer (score 0):

I think Cources.schema causing the issue. Here you can define the schema like this.

1st:

Schema part:

```
export const Cources = new Meteor.Collection('Cources');

Cources = attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  courcePath: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Cource path'
  },
  courceTitle: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Cource title',
    max: 200
  },
  courceDescription: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Cource description'
  },
  lessonsNumber: {
    type: Number,
    label: 'Lessons number',
    min: 1
  },
  courceDuration: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Cource duration'
  }
})
);
```

2nd :

Schema part:
    export const Cources;
    Cources.Collection = new Meteor.Collection('Cources');

```
Cources.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  courcePath: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Cource path'
  },
  courceTitle: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Cource title',
    max: 200
  },
  courceDescription: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Cource description'
  },
  lessonsNumber: {
    type: Number,
    label: 'Lessons number',
    min: 1
  },
  courceDuration: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Cource duration'
  }
});

Cources.Collection(Cources.schema);
```

And template part

```
<template name="AddCource_page">
  <div class="container">
    {{> quickForm collection="Cources.Collection" id="insertCourceForm" type="insert"}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything other than changing below syntax :

```
 Schemas.Cources = new SimpleSchema({});
 Cources.attachSchema(Schemas.Cources);
```

You have used **Cources.schema** instead of **Schemas.Cources**.